# I still can't delete folders using powershell administrator mode

Tags: windows, powershell

I still can't delete folders using powershell administrator mode
[powershell Delete result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRFqM.png)

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)> ls .\Sangfor\

    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Sangfor

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----          2022/12/23    22:18                SSL


PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Sangfor\SSL\SangforPWEx> ls

    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Sangfor\SSL\SangforPWEx

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---           2021/3/25    10:18         138056 atl100.dll
-a---            2022/5/5    22:05         533664 ECAgentProxy.dll
-a---           2021/3/25    10:18         773968 msvcr100.dll
-a---           2021/7/18    17:35        1610048 SangforPWAlive.dll
-a---            2022/5/6    17:45         440232 SangforPWEx.exe
-a---            2022/5/9     9:37         678312 SangforUDProtectEx_202251723165010.dll
-a---            2022/5/6    17:44        1397160 SangforUDProtectEx.exe
-a---           2021/3/25    10:18        2656360 sangforvpnlibcrypto-1_1.dll
-a---           2021/3/25    10:18         623208 sangforvpnlibssl-1_1.dll
```

I tried to delete the folder in the GUI, but it showed that the folder was occupied, but I could not close the program in the task manager. I also tried to delete using Windows' linux subsystem, but it showed I/O errors. I scanned the folder using anti-virus software and did not find the problem. I hope I can find a way to delete the folder.

Comment: probably cause theyre in use.

Comment: Yes, but I can't kill the process that uses the file

Comment: What happens if you restart your machine, and try to delete it then? Before you do, though, check if whatever's using the files is starting up with Windows. Also, what's preventing you from killing the process(es) which are using the files? What happens if you start `cmd` as an administrator, and try `taskkill /f /im <process_name>`?